# Livewire use validation from request but not append with giving id

Tags: laravel-livewire

Im trying to set a request validation in one place.

in App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest.php

```
$rules = [
  'username' => "required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-@.]+$/u|unique:users,username,{$this->id}",
  'email' => "required|email:filter|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-@.]+$/u|unique:users,email,{$this->id}",
  'firstname' => 'required',
  'lastname' => 'required',
  'phone' => ['nullable', new Phone, "unique:users,phone,{$this->id}"]
];
```

in livewire

```
protected function rules(): array
{
    return (new PostRequest())->rules();
}
```

and for live update

```
public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}
```

Now im working with mount user that have an id, but on live validate its keep say username is already taken is not correct.

My understand is `livewire` component property `$this->id` is not same in `ProfileRequest` that's why validation is keep fail. if im move rules into livewire everything work fine.

Is possible to keep validation rules in one place or keep it separate in `livewire` and `request`

Answer (score 0):

After spentime on research you can just use rules from request
here is a rules on request validation. here is a `ProfileRequest`

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array <string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    $withId = !empty($this->id) ? ",{$this->id}" : '' ;
    $rules = [
        'username' => "required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-@.]+$/u|unique:users,username{$withId}",
        'email' => "required|email:filter|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-@.]+$/u|unique:users,email{$withId}",
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'phone' => ['nullable', new Phone, "unique:users,phone{$this->id}"],
        'password' => 'required_if:id,=,null|min:6',
        'password_confirm' => 'required_if:id,=,null|same:password',
        'role' => 'required_if:id,=,null'
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

On livewire component you use request rules validation but it's gonna missing an id for use in unique rules. So you just override the rules by append by `$this->id` in livewire component

```
/**
 * Appending Rules
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    // Get Rule From Request
    $rules = (new ProfileRequest)->rules();

    // Override if have any unique column
    if (!empty($this->id)) {
        $withId = ",{$this->id}";
        $rules['username'] .= $withId;
        $rules['email'] .= $withId;

        array_pop($rules['phone']);
        array_push($rules['phone'], Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id));
    }

    // Return array rules
    return $rules;
}
```

So now you can keep a rules in one place.